# Why does this if statement equal this

Tags: python

What does the following code print? I know the answer is `TIME GREAT`. But I don't understand why it isn't `Right Cheer`. When it sets the score as `10`.

```
score = 10
if score < 10:
    print ("NOW")
    if score > 2:
        print ("RIGHT")
    elif score == 10:
        print ("CHEER")
else:
    print ("TIME")
print ("GREAT")
```

Comment: Because 10 is not less than 10.

Comment: but 10 is > that 2? so wouldnt that cause it to print "RIGHT"?

Comment: it won't passes the first if condition and so that it enters into the corresponding else block. Note that `if score > 2:` is within  `if score < 10:` condition.

Comment: Thank You very much. I now understand this question.

Comment: Please click the check mark next to one of the answers below, to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because input score is 10, which fails the `if` condition, and will jump to `else` part. Hence will print, `TIME GREAT`

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong and you need all elif's after the first if, your first `if` evaluates to `False` and the fact you have the others nested means they never get evaluated and you go straight to the `else` block:

```
score = 10
if score < 10:
    print ("NOW")
elif score > 2: 
    print ("RIGHT")
elif score == 10:
    print ("CHEER")
else:
    print ("TIME")
print ("GREAT")
```